# Enable dirty reads in MYSQL

Tags: mysql

I have a script that runs daily on a table that deletes the last 30 days worth of data and inserts new data in its place.

Sometimes, someone is querying the table when that script begins, which causes the script to fail because I cannot delete data while someone is querying - so we get lock timeouts.

I don't really care if we have dirty reads, I just need to make sure that the daily process runs, irrespective of what other users are doing.

Is there a way in MySQL to ensure that my DELETE + INSERT happens, irrespective of whatever queries are running on that table?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the queries you are running. Also write the transaction isolation levels you are using for your queries.

Comment: Have you tried using LOCK to lock the table during the update?  And if its multi step put it in a  Transaction block so that everything happens all at the same time so that it is not possible for a user to insert the same key into a table you are about to edit.

Comment: LOCK info found here --
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/lock-tables.html

Comment: And Transaction information here --  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/commit.html

Comment: @easleyfixed They're getting lock timeouts, so it seems like they're already doing that.

Comment: Interesting .. okay what about doing all the actions in a Transaction block so that they all get literally done in sequence regardless of outside activity.

Comment: Have you tried page or row-level locking?